# Python - Filter list of dictionaries based on if key value contains all items in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this, but with around 500 items:

```
listOfDicts = [{'ID': 1, 'abc': {'123': 'foo'}}, ... {'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123':'foo','456': 'bar'}}]

sampleFilterList = ['123', '456']
```

I am trying to filter the listOfDicts for all the results where all the values in the sampleFilterList are in the key 'abc'

The result should be a list:

```
[{'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123':'foo','456': 'bar'}}, ...]
```

I tried `[i for i in listOfDicts if a for a in sampleFilterList in i['abc']]`, but I am getting an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Consider removing the second item in the result list, as it is not clear where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert your second list to a set for more efficient comparisons:

```
sampleFilterSet = set(sampleFilterList)
```

Now, compare the 'abc' keys for each list item to the aforesaid set:

```
[item for item in listOfDicts if not (sampleFilterSet - item['abc'].keys())]    
#[{'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123': 'foo', '456': 'bar'}}]
```

This is the fastest solution. A more Pythonic (but somewhat slower) solution is to use `filter()`:

```
list(filter(lambda item: not (sampleFilterSet - item['abc'].keys()), listOfDicts))
#[{'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123': 'foo', '456': 'bar'}}]
```

Comment: What if the keys in item['abc'] also had other values that were not in sampleFilterSet? For example, if it contained 5 keys, 2 of which are in the set?

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you mind explaining the if not part of the statement? Is it checking for if all of the sampleSet is in item['abc'].keys()?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the *in* condition test before the *for* keyword in the list comprehension and also use `get` will be more safe, which returns a default value instead of throwing an error, if you are not sure if all the dictionaries in the list have the keyword `abc`:

```
listOfDicts = [{'ID': 1, 'abc': {'123': 'foo'}}, {'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123':'foo','456': 'bar'}}]    ​
sampleFilterList = ['123', '456']

[d for d in listOfDicts if all(s in d.get('abc', {}) for s in sampleFilterList)]
# [{'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123': 'foo', '456': 'bar'}}]
```

Or if use a set as of @DYZ, you can use `issubset`:

```
filterSet = set(sampleFilterList)
[d for d in listOfDicts if filterSet.issubset(d.get('abc', {}))]
# [{'ID': 7, 'abc': {'123': 'foo', '456': 'bar'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version with nested list comprehensions. Your problem is that the `a for a in...` is a list comprehension, and needs to be used in constructing a new list.

```
[i for i in listOfDicts if [a for a in sampleFilterList if a in i['abc']] == sampleFilterList]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in zip(listOfDicts):
 a = i[0]['abc']
 print (a)
```

or:

```
for i in zip(listOfDicts):
    if 'abc' in i[0]:
        a = i
        print (a)
```

This is an elegant way to do it, I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following one-liner:

```
passed_the_filter = [[dictionary_entry for dictionary_entry in list_of_dicts if filter_test in dictionary_entry['abc']] for filter_test in filter]
```

It is a nested list comprehension that iterates through both the filter and the dictionary list. It checks if the filter is a key in the dictionary entries' "abc" value. Your problem was that you used the wrong list comprehension syntax.

---

N.B. You may want to note that you might not be sure that an element has a "abc" key!

---

Thank you for reading this.